# how to search multipule string in Scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am using

```
val my_data = sc.textFile("abc.txt")
val my_search = my_data.filter(x => x.contains("is","work"))
```

where I am trying to filter the lines contains "is" and "work" in my RDD "My_Data"

Comment: you can create an array of strings and broadcast that array inside filter and use contains in each element of the array

Comment: `my_data.filter(x => x.contains("is") && x.contains("work"))`

Comment: Thanks for answer but its not working. below is my text file                         "This is my First Spark script
This is the first time i am working on spark                                                                             
i am very happy.                                                                          
I want to Thank everyone."   when i am executing the below command i am getting below output scala> val my_f = my_data.filter(x => x.contains("is") && x.contains("work")).collect
my_f: Array[String] = Array(This is the first time i am working on spark)

Answer (score 2):

If you know all the strings you want to filter beforehand (as in the example you gave), you can do the following:

```
my_data.filter(x => Seq("is", "work").forall(x.contains))
```

**Full words**

If you want to filter the full words, you will need to tokenize each line first. The easiest way to do it is by using a `string.split(" ")`. Be careful, as this doesn't work for languages like Japanese or Chinese.

```
my_data.filter { line => 
    val tokens = line.split(" ").toSet
    Seq("is", "work").forall(tokens.contains)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but its not working. below is my text file                           "This is my First Spark script                                                                          This is the first time i am working on spark                                                           i am very happy.                                                                                                  I want to Thank everyone.

Comment: when i am executing the below command i am getting below output  scala> val my_f = my_data.filter(x => Seq("is", "work").forall(x.contains)).collect
my_f: Array[String] = Array(This is the first time i am working on spark)

Comment: It's working. `sc.textFile` returns a `RDD[String]` where each row is a line. The line it's returning you after the filter contains both "is" and "work". I suppose you want to filter full words instead. I edited the answer for that

Comment: when i tried the above command its not returning anything,,                         val My_s = my_data.filter { line => 
     |     val tokens = line.split(" ").toSet
     |     Seq("is", "work").forall(tokens.contains)
     | }                                                                                                               scala> My_s.collect
res0: Array[String] = Array()     I don't know what is wrong.